# Textbox in a cell with rowspan doesn't apply width value

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a table  with labels and textbox.
some textbox has longer texts, so I want them to be wider.

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelEstado" runat="server" CssClass="labelGeneral">Estado:</asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEstado" runat="server" Enabled="False" CssClass="textboxDoble"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>

.textboxGeneral {
    width: 200px;
}

.textboxDoble {
    width: 400px;
}
```

In the VS editor it looks fine:
[image]

But in the Google Chrome or Firefox it doesn't work, "Estado" textbox is almost the same width than "Número de referencia", when it should be the double:

[image]

How can I make than the "Estado" textbox have the double width?
I also tried with "width: 100%".

Comment: try "min-width" for example. 
It's not easy to debug code like that. Try "inspect element" and debug your code there

Comment: Thanks. It works fine! I expected that it was a regular problem

Comment: Great! I will put it as an answer and then you accept it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "min-width"

```
.textboxGeneral {
    min-width: 200px;
}

.textboxDoble {
    min-width: 400px;
}
```